# Google chart: duplicate calls in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, google-visualization

I have a web application divided in two parts, one part is public and the other part is private. The public part works fine with Google Charts, but private part works wrong because duplicate calls to other functions.

To represent chart graphics I have defined the next directive:

```
privateApp.directive("columnChart", function(){
    return{
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {
            titleChart: "=",
            data: "=",
            columns: "=",
            min: "=",
            max: "=",
            vAxisTitle: "=",
            hAxisTitle: "=",
            tooltipColumn: "=",
            isClicked: "=",
            callbackFn: "&",
            width: "=",
            height: "="
        },
        link: function(scope, $elm, $attr){     
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            //Definimos las columnas que va a tener nuestra tabla de datos
            for (var i = 0; i < scope.columns.length; i++){
                data.addColumn(scope.columns[i].tipo, scope.columns[i].nombreColumna);
            };          

            var widthChart = 400;
            var heightChart = 400;
            if (scope.width != null)
                widthChart = scope.width;
            if (scope.height != null)
                heightChart = scope.height;

            scope.$watch("data", function (newValue, oldValue){
                scope.options = {
                        width: widthChart,
                        height: heightChart,
                        bar: {groupWidth: "95%"},
                        title: scope.titleChart,
                        legend: {position: "none"},
                        annotations: {
                            alwaysOutside: true
                        },
                        chartArea : {left:50,top:50,width:'90%',height:'80%'},
                        vAxis: {title: scope.vAxisTitle},
                        hAxis:  {title: scope.hAxisTitle, textPosition: "out"}
                };      
                if (scope.data != null){
                    //Eliminamos datos del DataTable
                    data.removeRows(0, data.getNumberOfRows());                 
                    //Insertamos filas a la tabla
                    for (var i = scope.min; i <= scope.max; i++){
                        data.addRow(scope.data[i]);
                    };


                    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
/*                  var cols = new Array();
                    for (var i = 0; i < scope.columns.length; i++){
                        if (i <= 1){
                            cols.push(i);
                            if (i == 1){
                                cols.push({calc: 'stringify', sourceColumn: 1, type: 'string', role: 'annotation'});
                            }
                        }else if (i == 2){
                            cols.push({calc: 'stringify', sourceColumn: 2, type: 'string', role: 'annotationText'});
                        }
                    }
                    for (var i = 0; i < cols.length; i++){
                        console.log(cols[i]);
                    }*/
                    //view.setColumns(cols);
                    view.setColumns([0, 1,
                                        {
                                            calc: "stringify",
                                            sourceColumn: 1,
                                            type: "string",
                                            role: "annotation"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            calc: "stringify",
                                            sourceColumn: scope.tooltipColumn,
                                            type: "string",
                                            role: "tooltip"
                                        }]);

                    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart($elm[0]);
                    //chart.draw(data, scope.options);
                    chart.draw(view, scope.options);
                    if (scope.isClicked){
                        //Detectamos el clic sobre el gráfico
                        google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, "click", selectHandler);                     
                    }                               
                }
            });

            scope.$watch("min", function (newValue, oldValue){
                scope.options = {
                        width: 400,
                        height: 400,
                        bar: {groupWidth: "95%"},
                        title: scope.titleChart,
                        legend: {position: "none"},
                        annotations: {
                            alwaysOutside: true
                        },
                        chartArea : {left:50,top:50,width:'90%',height:'80%'},
                        vAxis: {title: scope.vAxisTitle},
                        hAxis:  {title: scope.hAxisTitle, textPosition: "out"}
                };
                if (scope.data != null){
                    //Eliminamos datos del DataTable
                    data.removeRows(0, data.getNumberOfRows());
                    //Insertamos nuevos datos en la tabla
                    for (var i = scope.min; i <= scope.max; i++){
                        data.addRow(scope.data[i]);
                    };
                    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
                    view.setColumns([0, 1,
                                        {
                                            calc: "stringify",
                                            sourceColumn: 1,
                                            type: "string",
                                            role: "annotation"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            calc: "stringify",
                                            sourceColumn: scope.tooltipColumn,
                                            type: "string",
                                            role: "tooltip"
                                        }]);

                    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart($elm[0]);
                    chart.draw(view, scope.options);
                    if (scope.isClicked){
                        //Detectamos el clic sobre el gráfico
                        google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, "click", selectHandler);
                    }                               
                }
            });
            function selectHandler(e){
                var index;

                index = parseInt(e.targetID.substring("bar#0#".length, e.targetID.length));
                scope.callbackFn({arg1: data.getValue(index, 4)});
                //alert(data.getValue(index, 4));
            }
        }
    };
});
```

And in the layout, I have added this code which works fine in the public part and makes me to call twice functions when I load page or fire any event:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function(){
        angular.bootstrap(document.body, ["privateProfileModule"]);
    });
    google.charts.load("current", {packages: ["corechart"]});
</script>
```

You can check on the next picture the duplicate calls to the functions and the final error that I get.

[image]

I don't have any idea why this has happened.

**Edit 1:**

Each part of the web application public and private part have their own module, "publicProfileModule" and "privateProfileModule" respectively.

Comment: Do you use the `ng-app` directive in your markup as well? Or do you have any other calls to `angular.bootstrap()` in the code?

Comment: I have ng-app directive in my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only want to bootstrap AngularJS once. This is accomplished either by using the `ng-app="myAppModuleName"` directive, or manually calling `angular.bootstrap(rootElem, ['myAppModuleName'])`.

If you do both, AngularJS is fighting itself. Remove one of them.

Comment: So ... I can't to have two app's module in the same project? 
I want to say, Cant I have two different app's module in the same project? In my case, I have "privateApp" and "publicApp". in the same web application

Comment: You can have as many modules as you like, but you can only have one top level module that is bootstrapped for a given root element. You can have different modules running in completely separate parts of the same page, if you like, but not, for example, bootstrap two modules separately to use `document.body` as the root element on the same page. Instead, make one of the modules a dependency of the other and bootstrap the top level module only.

Comment: I think that my problem is that I have two top level modules. But I call one module in the private part and other in the public part in different pages, but maybe something is in cache and I need to make one dependent of the other or to have one main module and then two second level modules.